# Fragment not loading onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have two fragments and a main activity. The first fragment, ContactListFragment, is a list of contacts and the second fragment, ContactFragment, gathers the contact information and then sends that information back to the MainActivity to send to the ContactListFragment again. When you click the "Add Contact" button in the ContactFragment, the first fragment should load again and the updated list of contacts should be displayed. The onClick is working, I have a Toast message that displays and there is information inside my mCallback, but my first fragment doesn't load again when I click "Add Contact." I'm new to fragments, but from all the code I've seen I think I have it wired up correctly. So you don't have to go digging for it, this is the relevant code inside my onClick...

```
    OnSubmitListener mCallback = new OnSubmitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable) {

        }
    };

    //Container activity must implement this interface so that the fragment can deliver information
   public interface OnSubmitListener {
        public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable);
    }


    public void onAttach(MainActivity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnSubmitListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnSubmitListener");
        }
    }

    mAddContact = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddContactToArray);

    mAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

...

                mCallback.onSubmitClickedContacts(contact, position, updateVariable);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"I got clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

and here's the code inside my MainActivity. From what I can tell it all looks right. But my log message never runs and when I click the "Add Contact" button nothing happens.

```
@Override
public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable) {

    Log.d("TAG", "I got data");

    ContactListFragment firstFragment = new ContactListFragment();

    //ContactListFragment firstFragment = (ContactListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
      //      .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(CONTACT_OBJECT, contact);
    args.putInt(UPDATE_POSITION_INDEX, position);
    args.putString(UPDATE_VARIABLE_INDEX, updateVariable);
    firstFragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, firstFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Full code is below.

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activityToolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

   </FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppStatics, ContactListFragment.OnSubmitListener, ContactFragment.OnSubmitListener{

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ActionBar mActionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //wiring up the toolbar and action bars
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activityToolbar1);

        if (mToolbar != null) {
            //pass the activity toolbar
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


            mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            mActionBar.setSubtitle("Contact List");
        }
        if(findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) {
            //create an instance of NameFragment
            ContactListFragment firstFragment = new ContactListFragment();

            //in case this gets started with any special instructions from an
            //intent, pass the Intent extras as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            //add the fragment to the fragment_container FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer,firstFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }

    }

    public void onSubmitClicked (Contacts contact, int position) {

        ContactFragment secondFragment = new ContactFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(CONTACT_OBJECT, contact);
        args.putInt(UPDATE_POSITION_INDEX, position);
        secondFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, secondFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable) {

        Log.d("TAG", "I got data");

        ContactListFragment firstFragment = new ContactListFragment();

        //ContactListFragment firstFragment = (ContactListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
          //      .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(CONTACT_OBJECT, contact);
        args.putInt(UPDATE_POSITION_INDEX, position);
        args.putString(UPDATE_VARIABLE_INDEX, updateVariable);
        firstFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, firstFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }


}
```

ContactFragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

/**
 * Created by Spheven on 11/25/2015.
 */
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment implements AppStatics {

    private EditText mFirst;
    private EditText mLast;
    private EditText mEmailAddress;
    private EditText mPhone;
    private Button mAddContact;

    private String sFirstName;
    private String sLastName;
    private String sEmail;
    private String sPhone;

    private Contacts contact;

    ActionBar actionBar;

    String updateVariable = "add";
    int position;

    OnSubmitListener mCallback = new OnSubmitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable) {

        }
    };

    //Container activity must implement this interface so that the fragment can deliver information
   public interface OnSubmitListener {
        public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable);
    }


    public void onAttach(MainActivity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnSubmitListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnSubmitListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {

        contact = (Contacts) args.getSerializable(CONTACT_OBJECT);
        position = args.getInt(UPDATE_POSITION_INDEX, 0);



            mFirst.setText(contact.getmFirstName());
            mLast.setText(contact.getmLastName());
            mEmailAddress.setText(contact.getmEmail());
            mPhone.setText(contact.getmPhoneNumber());

            mAddContact.setText("Update");

            updateVariable = "update";
        }
        //wiring up text widgets
        mFirst = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
        mLast = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
        mEmailAddress = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        mPhone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editPhone);

        //wiring up add contact button. includes logic for required fields and sending contact back
        //to main activity

        mAddContact = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddContactToArray);

        mAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //check that required fields are filled in
                if (mFirst.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                    mFirst.setError("First name is required");

                } else if (mLast.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {

                    mLast.setError("Last name is required");
                } else {

                    //create new Contacts object and add information to it
                    sFirstName = mFirst.getText().toString();
                    sLastName = mLast.getText().toString();
                    sEmail = mEmailAddress.getText().toString();
                    sPhone = mPhone.getText().toString();

                    Contacts contact = new Contacts(sFirstName, sLastName, sEmail, sPhone);

                    mCallback.onSubmitClickedContacts(contact, position, updateVariable);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"I got clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_contact).setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_help).setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

ContactListFragment:

```
public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment implements AppStatics, ContactFragment.OnSubmitListener {

    private TextView mContactsAdded;
    private ListView mListView;

    ObjectArrayAdapter mAdapter;

    ArrayList<Contacts> contactsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Contacts contact;
    private String updateVariable;
    private int position;


    OnSubmitListener mCallback = new OnSubmitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSubmitClicked(Contacts contact, int position) {

        }
    };



    //Container activity must implement this interface so that the fragment can deliver information
    public interface OnSubmitListener {
        public void onSubmitClicked(Contacts contact, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnSubmitListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list,container,false);

        //wiring up the contactsAdded
        mContactsAdded = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textContactsAdded);
        mContactsAdded.setText("Contacts Added: " + contactsArrayList.size());


        //wiring up the adapter
        mAdapter = new ObjectArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.contacts_list, contactsArrayList);

        //wire up list view
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //display the list
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        //display the "no items to display" message only if list view is empty
        mListView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

        //set on click listener for listview
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                final Contacts contact = (Contacts) mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(CONTACT_OBJECT2, contact);
                intent.putExtra(UPDATE_POSITION_INDEX, position);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);*/

                mCallback.onSubmitClicked(contact, position);


            }
        });




 return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubmitClickedContacts(Contacts contact, int position, String updateVariable) {

        if (updateVariable.equals("update")) {

            contactsArrayList.set(position,contact);
        } else {
            contactsArrayList.add(contact);
        }

        mContactsAdded.setText("Contacts Added: " + contactsArrayList.size());


        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putSerializable(KEY_INDEX, contactsArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /*contactsArrayList = (ArrayList<Contacts>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(KEY_INDEX);

        mContactsAdded.setText("Contacts Added: " + contactsArrayList.size());
        mAdapter = new ObjectArrayAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.contacts_list, contactsArrayList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);*/
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.clear();
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);


        return true;
    }

    /*public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        if(android.R.id.home == 16908332) {

            menu.findItem(android.R.id.home).setVisible(false).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }*/


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_contact:
                ContactFragment secondFragment = new ContactFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, secondFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Help is on the way!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

}
```